# PHP Redirects, or cookies, not working on Godaddy, but working on localhost

Tags: php, redirect, cookies

So i've just uploaded my php to godaddy, except the redirects which were working have now stopped. There's supposed to be no difference between how code works on a live server to offline so i don't understand what's changed.

Here is a sample of the code which isn't working

The header link with the logout hyperlink which as far as i can tell acts as a hyperlink should

```
<div id="header">
           <div>
            <a href="index.php">Home</a> 
                <div id="loginreglink">
                <a href="Logout.php">Log Out</a>
                </div>
           </div>
          </div>
```

The actual Logout page (logout.php)

```
<?php

require_once ('Connection.php');

header('Refresh: 0;');

            if (!isset($_COOKIE['Username'])){
                require ('LoginFunctions.inc.php');
                redirect_user();
            } else {
                setcookie('Username', '', time()-60*60*24*90, '/', '', 0, 0);
                require ('RedirectPage.php');
                redirect_user();
            }


?>
```

RedirectPage.php (the next page which should link to, immediately after access of the logout page)

```
<?php
            require ('index.php');
            redirect_user();
?>
```

Which then immediately links back to index, however the user should be logged out. This isn't happening.

What happens is the page redirects to index (as it should) presumably using the following sequence, which leads me to think that the redirects are working, but the user isn't logged out. The cookie isn't removed. I don't really understand why it isn't though because it does work through netbeans on localhost.

Comment: Where is `redirect_user()` declared?

Comment: "There's supposed to be no difference between how code works on a live server to offline". I can't begin to tell you how wrong this is.

Comment: @MikeBrant So why not start explaining or link me to something that will help? rather than trying to make me feel dumb. I'm new, i know that, my teachers were useless so i'm teaching myself and as far as i have been able to tell, until now, all code that i've written has worked the same on and offline, and, i haven't seen (because i haven't made) any examples of code working differently till now.

Comment: @Spratters53 Two different servers, whether they be local or out at some hosting company somewhere, should never be assumed to have a similar environment unless you have somehow set them up to be similar and know for a fact they are running with same web server configurations, security settings, software versions, etc.  Understanding these various software dependencies which are the underpinnings of your application is something you are really only going to learn over time and with experience.  I was simply trying to dispel the notion that all environments are going to behave similarly.

Comment: You realize that you are calling `redirect_user()` twice in the "else" conditinal?  You call it once in the included `REdirectPage.php` file and than immediately after within the else condition.  Why is this?  What is code for `redirect_user()`?

Comment: I'm doing this on purpose, becuase i couldn't work out why when i logged out and redirected to index.php in the else clause it would delete the cookie, but the page would load with the cookie in place and then would lose the cookie either on refresh or when the user accessed another page. The second redirect therefore is there to ensure that the cookie is definitely gone from the browser and not deleted, but after loading.

Or at least, that was the impression my book gave me when i made it, but looking at it it seems like the first redirect is wasted as index redirect would be used 1st.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy. Unset the cookie.

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['Username'])){
   require ('LoginFunctions.inc.php');
   redirect_user();
} else {
   setcookie('Username', '', time()-60*60*24*90, '/', '', 0, 0);
   require ('RedirectPage.php');
   //add this
   unset($_COOKIE['Username'];
   //or use setcookie and make the time to expire in the past and just put an empty value like
   $cookie_name = "Username";
   $cookie_value = "";
   $time = -3600;
   setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $time, "/");
   redirect_user();  
}
```

Comment: That was simple, any ideas why unset cookie is needed when hosted?

Comment: `unset($_COOKIE['foo'])` does nothing to remove the cookie from the browser client instead only removing the variable from PHP's memory. You must send a header to expire the cookie on the browser client (as done through `setcookie()` typically).  I do think it is good practice to do both though if you want to keep your executing script free from this variable for the rest of its execution.

Comment: @MikeBrant This worked for a bit but now it doesn't unset the cookie properly. Now it seemingly deletes the cookie, and then when i select another page it resets the cookie again without me trying to log in.. Again though, this problem only occurs on the hosted website, not locally.